# Jquery 2.x use ajax code from Jquery 1.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Having a small problem with Jquery, in our system we load a lot of ajax files, we are using a Jquery 2.x, we have a requirement to run offline on IE 9+ so ajax would load from file:/// and it used to work when we were on Jquery 1.x

After doing some digging I found out that Jquery 2.x has dropped activeX support. Which is what I need to get the JSON files on IE. So my question is, is there a way of having Jquery 2.x and then just after it load only the ajax code for Jquery 1.x?

Comment: If you need jQuery 1.x, use jQuery 1.x instead of 2.x.  jQuery 2.x is for environments where old IE support is not needed.  It just sounds like you're using the wrong version of jQuery.  You can write some code to load a different version of jQuery and assign it to a different symbol so it can be used independently, but why load two versions of jQuery if what you actually  need is 1.x?

Comment: No need, just use 1.x, because 2.x is exactly like 1.x sans IE9 support.

Comment: Why would you need activeX to load from file:///, am I missing something?

Comment: @FrancescoMM if I don't need activeX then why does my ajax not work offline in IE9+

Comment: @ryuutatsuo no idea. Maybe because JQ2.x does not support ie9? Anyway I think you can read a (server) file without JQuery, and without ActiveX in any browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own problem by discovering $.ajaxTransport which allows you to implement your own ajax functionality. Thanks to this I was able to check if ActiveX is supported and add the necessary logic to make everything work.

```
$.ajaxTransport( "* text html xml json", function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
            if( /* perform check here for scenario your trying to fix*/) {
                return {
                  send: function( headers, completeCallback ) {
                      //create your logic here and have it return 
                      completeCallback(status, statusText, responses, headers);
                  },
                  abort: function() {}
                };
              }
        });
```